# Use a function to generate a Gatling feeder

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

I'm using Gatling  3.3.1 to inject data in Kafka using the [gatling-kafka](https://github.com/mnogu/gatling-kafka) library.
I'm trying to use a small custom feeder to test it.

```
  val feeder = Iterator.continually(Map("email" -> (Random.alphanumeric.take(20).mkString + "@foo.com")))
  val scn: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("Kafka Test")
  .feed(feeder)
.exec(
  kafka("request")
    .send[String]("${email}")
)
```

But it doesn't work
feed() expects a FeederBuilder an feeder is Iterator[Map[String,String]]

I don't know how is the correct way to fix / do this.

Answer (score 0):

It compiles properly on my side. I recommend you try with an up-to-date version of Gatling. The current one is 3.4.2 and 3.5.0 will be out next week.

Comment: Okey, I fixed it after checking the imports of the code. Thanks for the info